# Add Custom Link to Top Link in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks

I want to add custom link in the 'top link' section(white list, Login, Account).

Basically i want to add "Blog" link at the top of the links. When user click on the link then its redirect to the external website.

My website URL is www.imageplus.pk.

Please help me how can i do this?

Comment: Did it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new link just do this

Open `app/design/frontend/default/TEMPLATE/layout/customer.xml`

Add the following at the bottom before closing  tag.

```
    <default>
    <reference name="top.links">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Blog</label>
        <url>YOUR-BLOG-URL</url>
        <title>Bloh</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>2</position>
        <liParams />
       <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
      </action>
    </reference>
    </default>
```

Just replace URL with your blog url

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" />
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: now my blog link is showing but now i want to hide the "register" link and give a external hyperlink to blog to open in new window. thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer, the Register url helper could also be "customer/getLoginUrl"

Comment: its open the url in same window, but i want to open it in new window. thanks

Comment: Did you add target=_blank

Comment: this is my code:                                                                                                                       <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Blog</label>
            <url>http://www.tumblr.com</url>
            <title>Blog</title>
            <prepare/>
             <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
   <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
         </action>

Comment: ok please try again now, this one works in my setup i just checked

Comment: i try it but it still open in same window, http://imageplus.pk you can check it. thanks

Comment: this code is works... <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
   <label>Blog</label>
   <url>http://www.tumblr.com</url>
   <title>Blog</title>
   <prepare/>
   <urlParams/>
         <position>100</position>
   <liParams />
   <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
  </action>

Comment: If it works now just mark it as correct answer please

Comment: how can i mark it correct answer

Comment: There is a mark to check it as correct answer (v)

Answer (score 1):

Top-links are managed in magento through layout xml files. To add a link to top links, we need to add xml code to layout files.

> Add Blog link with external URL

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Blog</label>
        <url>http://www.linktoblog.com</url>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <position>2</position>
      </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

> Remove register link

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" />
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

For more detail, you can refer below URLs:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-add-top-links-in-magento/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240780/2199172

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hi, thanks,  now i can add the blog link at the top of links, but i want to hide the "register" link. and put the external hyperlink to the "blog" link.

Comment: I have updated my answer